# Could not load file or assembly. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have solution and couple projects inside. I cannot figure out why i get this error. I cannot figure out where this is coming from so far. I was looking at all projects references and bin folders. At the end i do not see anything related to this.I tried also going to projects properties on references tab but didn't find anything related. Tried to clear/rebuild etc. What can i do more to found this and remove from the solution?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ZipTools, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Definitely there is some piece of code in your project that relies on ZipTools assembly. Can you please tell us when this error occurs, and in which project? Does this error appears in runtime or during compile time?

Comment: Maybe a DLL you are referencing have dependencies on that ZipTools

Comment: this is asp.net application i get this error on the webpage so runtime. I tried to find everything starting with name: "Zip" and haven't found anything.

Comment: In visual studio Solution Explorer view, if you expand the 'references' node of the various projects do any of them show a small red x icon?  Also, as matteo noted, it could possibly be a dependency to something else you've referenced.  If you're using nuget try to restore all your packages.

Answer (score -4):

Make sure you added reference to dll. Make sure you have referenced all the assemblies and they are with the same version. Delete the Bin and obj folders of the project manually, Clean and Rebuild it.

Comment: done already i mentioned about it.